# parsing error with braces in react: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag. Did you want a JSX fragment <>...</>?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react but have this snippet of code

```
    return (
        <div>
            dropdown ? (<li className='goal-list-item' onClick={() => setDropdown(!dropdown)}>{goal.name}</li>) :
        (
            <li className='goal-list-item-shown' onClick={() => setDropdown(!dropdown)}>{goal.name}</li>
                <div className='goal-info'>{goal.time_to_finish}</div>
        )
        </div>
    )
```

If I don't use {} curly braces, I see the actual text, but if I put the curly braces around

```
            {dropdown ? (<li className='goal-list-item' onClick={() => setDropdown(!dropdown)}>{goal.name}</li>) :
        (
            <li className='goal-list-item-shown' onClick={() => setDropdown(!dropdown)}>{goal.name}</li>
                <div className='goal-info'>{goal.time_to_finish}</div>
        )}
```

I get multiple errors that I can't figure out. I am denoting the javascript with curly braces and the executable code with parenthesis, and yet there are still issues syntax issues

The error shows up in the div nested within a list item with this response `Line 12:17:  Parsing error: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag. Did you want a JSX fragment <>...</>?`

The issue seems to be with this line

```
<div className='goal-info'>{goal.time_to_finish}</div>
```

because when I remove it the errors go away, but I'm having a tough time figuring out why

Comment: adding to @imiro ans... in jsx regular js operation should happen inside `{}`. Since you are using ?: operator it should be sounded by `{}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within parenthesis ( .. ) you can only have single root jsx tag. So this would work:

```
        (
<div>
            <li className='goal-list-item-shown' onClick={() => setDropdown(!dropdown)}>{goal.name}</li>
                <div className='goal-info'>{goal.time_to_finish}</div>
</div>
        )
```

Please refer forex. here for background: https://www.quora.com/Why-does-react-only-allow-one-DOM-element-to-be-rendered

Comment: why does adding an extra div fix it though?

Comment: It relates to javascript it self not able to return but single values and the react code of single div transpiles into below example:

render() {
 return (
   React.createElement("div", null)
 );
}

Answer (score 0):

That’s because JSX elements must be wrapped with enclosing tag in React as the error message suggests. It is thrown because in your ternary expression the falsy value will return

```
<li></li>
<div></div>
```

without enclosing tag like this

```
<div>
   <li></li>
   <div></div>
</div>
```

If your goal is to eliminate the parent `<div>` when it is parsed, you could use `<React.Fragment>` to wrap the expression.